# How do I prove that $\sqrt[5]{80\sqrt 5+176}=1+\sqrt 5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

How do I prove that $\sqrt[5]{80\sqrt 5+176}=1+\sqrt{5}$?

I have no idea how to proceed except just raising both sides to the power of $5$ and expanding $ \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{5}$ using the binomial theorem

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach to me. Do you not like it?

Comment: @Arthur I wanted to arrive at the RHS solely from the LHS, instead of starting from both sides

Comment: I don't think I can do that with $\sqrt{3 + 2\sqrt2}=1+\sqrt2$, much less your expression.

Comment: How do I determine the exact value (if it exists) of $\ \sqrt[5]{243}\ $ *without* trial and improvement?

Comment: @AdamRubinson, you could factorise $243$ in prime factors and then simplify the root.

Comment: @Angelo If the aim from the outset is to "find $\sqrt[5]{243}$," then "factorising $243$ in prime factors" doesn't have much purpose, other than to hopefully coincidentally give the same outcome as the first step in trial and improvement, which is basically *guessing what the answer is*.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, it is not guessing,  you are not guessing the factorization of a number but you are applying the divisibility criteria, moreover factorization permits in many cases to simplify a root unless the number is prime or the exponents of its factorization cannot be simplify with the index of the root. Also you can take a factor out the root if its exponent is greater o igual to the index of the root.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think we can all agree that the *easiest* way to prove, or to "see" that $\sqrt[5]{80\sqrt 5+176}=1+\sqrt 5$ is by using the binomial theorem.

If you're in an exam and they expect you to simplify $\sqrt[5]{80\sqrt 5+176}$ to $1+\sqrt 5$ without using a calculator, then surely the best way is by trialling different values of $m$ an $n$ for: $(m+n\sqrt{5})^5,\ $ and seeing of any of them match.

In terms of preparing for an exam where you are expected to be able to simplify like this quickly without a calculator, the only way to improve time-wise is by memorising a big chunk of Pascal's triangle. But then this exam (question) seems to me to be a bit silly, as it is requiring you to waste a chunk of your brain's memory storage without much reward. Luckily, I don't think there are many exams that have questions that require you to do this.

Comment: As it happens, $$(m+n\sqrt{5})^5= m (m^4 + 50 m^2 n^2 + 125 n^4)
 + 5 \sqrt{5}\,n (m^4 + 10 m^2 n^2 + 5 n^4)$$ so it's relatively easy to *guess* $m=n=1$.

Comment: @Blue Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying and is what I would do if I had to simplify $\sqrt[5]{80\sqrt 5+176}$ in an exam without a calculator.

Comment: Indeed. I was simply showing explicitly that the strategy would have worked pretty nicely in this case. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite our radical as $\sqrt[5]{\frac{160\sqrt{5}+352}{2}} $ to enable us to factor out $32$ from the root.
$$\Longrightarrow\sqrt[5]{32}*\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt{5}+11}{2}}$$
By equating both sides:
$$\Longrightarrow2\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt{5}+11}{2}}=1+\sqrt{5}$$
$$\Longrightarrow\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt{5}+11}{2}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\phi$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{5\sqrt{5}+11}{2}=\phi^5$$
Since $\phi^2=\phi+1$ we can rewrite $\phi^5$ easily as $\phi(\phi+1)^2=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2$
$$\Longrightarrow\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{11+5\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: How did you get:

$$\Longrightarrow2\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt{5}+11}{2}}=1+\sqrt{5}$$

without using a calculator?

Comment: [“I think you should be more explicit in step two.“](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Then-a-Miracle-Occurs-Copyrighted-artwork-by-Sydney-Harris-Inc-All-materials-used-with_fig2_302632920)

Comment: @AdamRubinson we're proving that this whole expression is equal to $1+\sqrt{5}$ so I equated the two sides.

Comment: How did you equate the two sides without using the Binomial expansion?

Comment: It's a forwards-backwards proof, we know the result and we're just showing it, no?

Comment: One interpretation of the question is that it's a proof question, where OP clearly doesn't want to use the Binomial theorem. If this was your interpretation, then your so-called "proof" is nonsensical. Firstly, you can't start with what you're trying to prove in order to prove it, which it looks like what you are trying to do. Secondly, most of your lines are not mathematical statements. The line:

$$\Longrightarrow\sqrt[5]{32}*\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt{5}+11}{2}}$$ is not a coherent mathematical statement.

So I'm baffled as to why you have any upvotes at all.

Answer (score 1):

$$\large\sqrt[5]{80\sqrt 5+176}=\sqrt[5]{(1+\sqrt5)^5}=1+\sqrt5$$

Remember that: $$\color{red}{176+80\sqrt{5}}=(1+\sqrt5)^5$$

using a calculator to developed $(1+\sqrt5)^5$.

Comment: I like the "remember that". No doubt it's something everyone remembers, and if you weren't told beforehand that the answer is $1+\sqrt{5}$, you would have instantly "remembered" this. (but, granted, we have all done this during an exam, after an hour of sweating to at last find a solution by chance: "we easily observe that...")

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Ahahahahah :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, I agree with Jean-Claude, he is definitely right.

Comment: @Angelo Hi Angelo. I have taken the observation of the textbooks of high school :-)

Comment: I'm guessing this is all in jest, right? Or are you guys serious that you *remember* that $176+5\sqrt{5}+75\sqrt{5}=(1+\sqrt5)^5\ ?$ But you can't be serious about this, surely...

Comment: @AdamRubinson I am serious. I surely imagined that to have $1+\sqrt5$ the radical had to be the fifth power of it. I developed it and got it right.

Comment: @downvoter: What is the reason of this downvote?

Comment: I downvoted because I don't understand this. To me, this is nonsense. Sorry

Comment: @AdamRubinson The reasoning is right but I accept your thinking.

Comment: Are you saying that I should also "remember" what $(1+\sqrt3)^7 $ and $(2+\sqrt5)^9 $ are, from memory? That's a lot of things to remember, and without much purpose other than clogging up my working memory with not much reward. So no, I don't get what you are saying.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I don't remember it by heart but I had it developed by a calculator

Comment: What do you mean, you had it "developed by a  calculator" ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I have solved $(1+\sqrt5)^5$ by a calculator and I have seen that is coincides with the radicand.

Comment: If you're allowed to use a calculator, then why not just type in "$\sqrt[5]{80\sqrt 5+176}$" and the calculator will simplify it for you.

Comment: Can you clarify what are equivalences, implications or equalities? Currently this reads $\sqrt[5]{80\sqrt 5+176}\iff \cdots =\sqrt[5]{176+80\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt[5]{(1+\sqrt5)^5}=1+\sqrt5$, and I cannot recognise how it answers the question how to derive the RHS from the LHS (if you don't know the answer beforehand).

Comment: @AdamRubinson The calculator does not. I had a little bit of intuition to get the identity.

Comment: @MartinR OK. You're right

Comment: @Sebastiano most modern calculators simplify surds for you as much as possible.

Comment: The thing is, if you had a calculator expand $(1+\sqrt5)^5$, you did precisely what the OP is trying to avoid. A more "correct" way might be, for instance, to expand $(a+b\sqrt{5})^5$ with no assumption on $a$ and $b$, but you get a system of equations of degree $5$, and some work to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I can see how the wording "remember that..." is mysterious but the point of the proof is correct. If we are trying to prove that the fifth root of something is a binomial then it makes sense to apply the binomial theorem to that binomial to the fifth power to see if equality holds.

Answer (score 1):

Consider: $\sqrt[5]{176 + 80 \, \sqrt{5}}$. Both integer values are multiples of $16$, or $2^4$, and leads to $\sqrt[5]{2^4 \, (11 + 5 \sqrt{5})}$. Now,
\begin{align}
11 + 5 \, \sqrt{5} &= 6 + 5 \, \sqrt{5} + 5 = (1 + 2 \, \sqrt{5} + 5) + 5 + 3 \, \sqrt{5} \\
&= (1 + \sqrt{5})^2 + \sqrt{5} \, (3 + \sqrt{5}) \\
&= (1 + \sqrt{5})^2 \, \left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^2 \, (2 + \sqrt{5})}{2}.  
\end{align}
Using $$2 + \sqrt{5} = \frac{16 + 8 \, \sqrt{5}}{8} = \frac{1 + 3 \, \sqrt{5} + 3 \,(\sqrt{5})^2 + 5 \, \sqrt{5}}{8} = \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^3}{2^3} $$
then
$$ 11 + 5 \, \sqrt{5} = \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^5}{2^4} $$
and
$$ \sqrt[5]{176 + 80 \, \sqrt{5}} = \sqrt[5]{2^4 \, \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^5}{2^4}} = \sqrt[5]{(1 + \sqrt{5})^5} = 1 + \sqrt{5}.$$

Following the same pattern one can determine that $\sqrt[5]{176 - 80 \, \sqrt{5}} = 1 - \sqrt{5}$ which leads to the statement
$$ \sqrt[5]{175 \pm 80 \, \sqrt{5}} = 1 \pm \sqrt{5}. $$